# CSS nth of type choosing all images

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to have all odd images floating to the left and all eben images floating to the right.

```
    <section id="about">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="about-item">
                <img src="img/about1.png" alt="About">
                <h2>About Us</h2>
                <p>Suspendisse efficitur consequat condimentum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="about-item">
                <img src="img/about2.jpg" alt="Apporach">
                <h2>Professional Approach</h2>
                <p>Curabitur justo turpis, pellentesque rhoncus dignissim non, consequat eget ante.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

To do that, my logic was that every even image whose parent is #about should float to right, etc. Just like this:

```
#about img:nth-of-type(2n+1){
  float:left;
}

#about img:nth-of-type(2n){
  float:right;
}
```

It seems though that all images float on the left of the screen which I do not understand. How do I solve this?

Comment: Your selectors are wrong as mentioned by others but you can also use 'odd' and 'even' keywords:
https://jsfiddle.net/43rfzcp5/5/

Comment: You fundamentally misunderstand `nth-of-type` (and also probably `nth-child`). Read about it. `nth-of-type` refers only to elements that have the same parent element (or in other words, who are siblings).

Comment: @connexo Thank you for your insightful comment. If I found a good source, I wouldn't have posted here.

Comment: *The :nth-of-type(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, of the same type (tag name), **of its parent**.* https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: Your images are not siblings, that is, they don't share the same parent element, and as such, you cannot work on the images with the `nth-of-type` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors in this situation need to be `.about-item:nth-of-type(2n+1) img` and `.about-item:nth-of-type(2n) img`.

`nth-of-type` always and only counts its "n" factor *inside*  its own parent element, not for the whole document.

```css
.about-item:nth-of-type(2n+1) img{
  float:left;
}

.about-item:nth-of-type(2n) img{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
    <section id="about">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="about-item">
                <img src="img/about1.png" alt="About">
                <h2>About Us</h2>
                <p>Suspendisse efficitur consequat condimentum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="about-item">
                <img src="img/about2.jpg" alt="Apporach">
                <h2>Professional Approach</h2>
                <p>Curabitur justo turpis, pellentesque rhoncus dignissim non, consequat eget ante.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This does not make sense to me in a logical sense; 

".about-item:nth-of-type(2n+1) img" 

To me, this reads "look inside a .about-item class, and if any odd element is an image, float it". Doesn't it go through each instance of the class individually? Why would it count the occurences across all instances?

Comment: no, it means "count the `divs` which have class `.about-item` and apply the different rules to the `img` elements inside them, depending on which div is an odd or even child  of its parent element (i.e. `section#about` in this case), and also look at the type of the element (i.e. div). Actually in this particular example it will work the same way if you use nth-child selectors instead of the nth-of-type selectors.

Comment: Why not replace `2n+1` by `odd` and `2n` by `even`?

Comment: @connexo Sure, that's possible, but I used what had been used in the question